# deleting users from table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i have a table listing all users on the site:

```
<?php $pt_table = '<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete user?\');"><table id="patients">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>User id</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Added on</th>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>';


            $x=1;
            foreach ($users as $patient) {

                $pt_table .= '<tr';  if ($x % 2 == 0) {$pt_table .=' class="alt"';}
                $pt_table .= '>';
                $pt_table .=  '<td><a href="profile.php?username='.$patient['username'].'">'.$patient['username'].'</a></td>
                   <td>'.$patient['id'].'</td>
                   <td>'.$patient['email'].'</td>
                   <td>'.$patient['joined'].'</td>
                   <td>';
                if ($patient['group'] == 1) { $pt_table .= 'User';} elseif ($patient['group'] == 2) { $pt_table .= 'Administrator';}
                $pt_table .= '</td><td><input id="gobutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px" /></td>';
                $pt_table .= '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$patient['id'].'"';

                $pt_table .='</td></tr>';

                $x++;
            }
            $pt_table .='</table></form>';
            echo '<br><br/><br/><br/>';
            echo $pt_table;
```

i want to delete a specific record when user clicks the corresponding button on the table it deletes that record. here is the delete code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['user_id']) && $_POST['user_id'] !== '') {


            if ($admin->deleteuser($_POST['user_id']) == true) {
                header('Location:add-user.php?deleted');
            } else {
                $msg->add('e', 'The was a problem deleting user.');
            }
        }
```

the problem is the last record on the table gets deleted not the one that the user pressed the remove button to delete. what am i doing wrong please?

Comment: _“the problem is the last record on the table gets deleted”_ – that is not surprising, because the _whole_ form with _all_ its input fields gets submitted, and PHP has the habit of letting multiple parameters of the same name overwrite each other, so that only the last one “survives”. You need to either create a seperate form for each user (that would then have to be inside a `td`), or transmit the info which user to delete with the respective submit button itself, because between the submit button and the hidden input there is no connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is including *every* user all in one form.  And re-using the `name` attributes on each one.  So when the form posts to the server it's probably only using whatever was the last form element with that `name` (in this case `user_id`).

So basically, your HTML simplified looks something like this:

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input ... />
        <input ... />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input ... />
        <input ... />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- and so on... ->
  </table>
</form>
```

In order to discern between each user, you can wrap them in their own individual forms.  Something more like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <input ... />
        <input ... />
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <input ... />
        <input ... />
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- and so on... ->
</table>
```

That way each form would have just one hidden `input` with the `user_id` and one submit button.  You'd do this by modifying the HTML you're emitting so that the `form` tags are inside the loop.  Keep in mind that the entire `form` should probably be in a single `td`, I don't think putting `form` tags around the `tr` itself would be valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you have only one form and have multiple

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" >
```

the easy solution for you to change your approche like this

change your submit button  to

```
<input   type="button"   value="Remove"
onclick="window.location.href=\'?deleteuser_id='.$patient['id'].'\'; "
 style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px" />
```

then

```
if ( isset($_GET['deleteuser_id']) && $_GET['deleteuser_id'] !== '') {


            if ($admin->deleteuser($_GET['deleteuser_id']) == true) {
                header('Location:add-user.php?deleted');
            } else {
                $msg->add('e', 'The was a problem deleting user.');
            }
        }
```

Comment: General rule-of-thumb: One should not use GET for requests that _modify_ server-side data, but stick to POST.

Comment: thank you for input. id prefer not to use GET for this.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
 $pt_table .= '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$patient['id'].'"';
```

to:

```
 $pt_table .= '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$patient['id'].'" />"';
```

Closing the tag, and the value attribute will help.

Comment: thank you was syntax error on my part. fixed it but didnt solve delete problem.